# not able to kill other process

Tags: android, kill-process

I want to kill other application, I have googled and see other answer on stackoverflow but didn't get satisfied answer. Here I am trying to kill browse app (for testing). What I want to do is, I want to kill application using package name.

```
    Log.d("Process", "in intent");
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> pids = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
    int processid = 0;
    Log.d("Process",String.valueOf(pids.size()) );
    for(int i = 0; i < pids.size(); i++)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"on if", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = pids.get(i);
        if(info.processName.equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.browser")){
            Log.d("Process", "in if");
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"in if", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           processid = info.pid;
           Log.d("Process",String.valueOf(processid) );
           android.os.Process.sendSignal(pids.get(i).pid, android.os.Process.SIGNAL_KILL);
           android.os.Process.killProcess(processid);

        } 
    }
```

this is my code can someone help me out? what i am missing?

in logcat I am getting sending signal. PID :1524 SIG: 9

Comment: You "didn't get satisfied" because **you are not supposed to do that**, something the other answers no doubt made rather clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**READ FIRST, IMPORTANT: You can only kill a process that has the same userID as the one that is doing the killing**. If you are trying to kill your own process it should work. Otherwise you can't do it (**unless you have a rooted device and your application has root priviledges**).

---

You'd need to use `ActivityManager`: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html for the process info.

You could:

1. Get all running app processes.
2. Find your app.
3. Get its PID.

When you get the `PID`:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(PID);
```

Comment: so you are trying say that i can't kill browser or anyother application though i have there PID?

Comment: nope, I'm saying you cannot kill any other app if you're not **root**

Comment: ok.. i one more question :P . Q1) what if i have non rooted device but some how i can gain root permission in this sectution can i kill other apps?

Comment: root privileges in your app will be useless if you don't have a rooted device...This is for security reasons....

Comment: [take look to the articles of this search](https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20root%20security%20risk)